# Preisrichtertätigkeit

Tags: translation, meaning

Living in Germany for quite a while now, working as an architekt, I stumbled over the word *Preisrichtertätigkeit.* Anyone a clue what this expression means?

Comment: Welcome, translation questions are not allowed, since, without a previous attempt, they're not considered a *fine point of the language*. Please read the guidelines [here.](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/343/when-is-a-translation-request-to-german-off-topic)

Comment: However, it is safe to assume here that this word is not contained in any dictionary.

Comment: I agree @Wrzlprmft. But even [Preisrichter](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Preisrichter) does appear, of course *Tätigkei* does as well. Now, as I see it, the problem isn't the question, but the lack of an attempt. Suppose, you are not German(-speaking); not only that, but suppose also that you haven't read too much German, and thus, you don't have idea how to divide the word, hence you fail in finding its correct splitting, and instead give it a try to `*reisricht*`. Then you *try* searching `http://www.dict.cc/?s=*reisricht*`, and even so, voilà!, you'd be able to eventually find your word.

Answer (score 8):

A "Preisgericht" is a jury, mainly in the context of sports and arts. A "Preisrichter" is a member of such a jury. "Preisrichtertätigkeit" basically means that somebody works or worked as a "Preisrichter".

Comment: Well, to be exact, it means the act of working as a "Preisrichter", not that somebody works as a "Preisrichter".

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the link in the question (that has now been removed), where "Preisrichtertätigkeit" was used like one point in a CV.

Answer (score 2):

It means being in a jury for a contest in which the participants (or one of them) get prices.

Preis = price,
Richter = judge,
Tätigkeit = activity, occupation